# Problems after adding Linux Deepin repository

Tags: package-management, repository

I added Linux Deepin repository to Ubuntu but I don't install anything.
I used this commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and everything on Ubuntu went wrong. I guess part of Ubuntu updated from Linux Deepin repository and now I don't know how to make a roll back on the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming "Linux Deepin" broke most of the system files.  I would suggest reinstallation since your system is now unusable, according to an answer you wrote (which should have been a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling 'ubuntu-desktop' or 'dde-meta-core' may solve your problem.

But apt-get may not be able to work (happened with me), use aptitude instead :)

sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop

or

sudo aptitude install  dde-meta-core

But you will not be able to keep both of them... It's a compiz package conflict.., I think!
I'm also searching for a better solution..
Plz.. post any solution you found to be useful